# how was R. Daneel Olivaw's skin manufactured?

Tags: robots, isaac-asimov, laws-of-robotics

R. Daneel Olivaw had such realistic skin that he was able to live and work as a human being even though he was secretly a robot.  What was Daneel's skin made of? And how was his skin manufactured?

> “Our own robots … Well, you can tell they’re robots, you understand.
>   You look like a Spacer.”
>
> “Oh, I see. You expected a rather crude model and were surprised. Yet
>   it is only logical that our people use a robot of pronounced humanoid
>   characteristics in this case if we expected to avoid unpleasantness.
>   Is that not so?” - <sub><sup>[The Caves of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Caves_of_Steel)</sup></sub>

Comment: I really doubt you can get authoritative answer. AFAIR Asimov didn't disclose in detail robots' technical specifications in his books (at least in _Robot series_).

Comment: @hindmost - Agreed. Caves of Steel and Robots of Dawn mention that the skin is "skinlike" and has "pores and hairs" but that's about it really. Note that Olivaw can remove the skin with trivial ease so it's clearly not bonded to his exoskeleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. Daneel Olivaw appeared in seven of Asimov's novels (and one short story), but Asimov did not provide too many details on Daneel's skin.

**What was Daneel's skin made of?**
Asimov made it clear from the beginning, i.e. in “[The Caves of Steel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2266),” that Daneel's skin is artificial:

> R. Daneel let his arm rest easily in the plain-clothes man’s grip. Baley stared at it, pinching the skin along the median line. Was there a faint seam?
>       It was logical, of course, that there should be. A robot, **covered with synthetic skin**, and deliberately made to look human, could not be repaired in the ordinary  fashion.

This was confirmed 30 years later in “[The Robots of Dawn](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1289)”:

> “Do you have real skin on your face, Daneel? It’s an extraordinary imitation if it isn’t.” She reached toward him and her hand rested delicately on his cheek. “It even feels right.”
>       “Nevertheless, madam, **it is not real skin**. It does not heal of its own accord—if cut. On the other hand, **a tear can easily be welded closed** or a patch can even be replaced.”

So we only know that Daneel's skin is made of an unknown synthetic material that can be welded.

**And how was his skin manufactured?**
Asimov's works do not contain any details on the manufacturing of Daneel's skin. However, Daneel is not the only humanoid robot that Asimov had devised. There are, for example, Tony (“[Satisfaction Guaranteed](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44203)”), Andrew Martin (“[The Bicentennial Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41611)”) and Stephen Byerley. Regarding the latter, Alfred Lanning of U.S. Robots is asked in “[Evidence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41426)” if it were possible to create a humanoid robot:

> Lanning harrumphed and considered, “It’s been done experimentally by U.S. Robots,” he said reluctantly, “without the addition of a positronic brain, of course. **By using human ova and hormone control, one can grow human flesh and skin over a skeleton of porous silicone plastics** that would defy external examination. The eyes, the hair, the skin would be really human, not humanoid. And if you put a positronic brain, and such other gadgets as you might desire inside, you have a humanoid robot.”

Obviously this method is not compatible with the information from the robot novels, but at least here Asimov actually described the manufacturing process for the skin of a humanoid robot.